# Convert date format from YYYY-MM to --MMMYYYY: 2018-02 to --FEB2018

Tags: r, date

I want to convert the char type dates (2018-05-25, 2018-03, etc) to 25May2018, --Mar2018 (Missing dates should be replaced by "--" (eg.--Mar2018)

```
Unique ID      A (Character format)          B (Required result - it should be in uppercase)
1            2018-05-25                  25MAY2018
2            2018-04                     --APR2018
3            2018-03-28                  28MAR2018
4            2018-05                     --APR2018
5            2018-05-25                  25MAY2018
```

Comment: Have you tried lubridate?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @RonakShah, i need to create a variable with the above condition

Comment: Yes, but why? Where are you going to use it? Is it only for display purpose?

Comment: The condition is like that so i need to create it....yes it s only for display purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can solve this by dividing the dates in two parts. First part would be the dates that has the day part, second part of dates would be without it.

```
x <- c('2018-05-25', '2018-04', '2018-03-28', '2018-05', '2018-05-25')
dates <- as.Date(x)
new_dates <- toupper(format(dates, '%d%b%Y'))
new_dates[is.na(new_dates)] <- toupper(format(as.Date(paste0(x[is.na(dates)], 
                                       '-01')), '--%b%Y'))
new_dates
#[1] "25MAY2018" "--APR2018" "28MAR2018" "--MAY2018" "25MAY2018"
```